# Test script for description box

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I am trying to write a selenium script - I click on detail button and instead of displaying details of item it displays error message. I want to fail the script but don't know how to write it and from this page I can not navigate to other pages. Please help me to write test code in junit selenium[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXyRC.png)

Comment: Please add code and define your problem better, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking on detail button, you can check if text of that element contains error message, if so then you can mark the test case as fail explicitly or you can use assertion also in this case.

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(<any selector of your relevance>);
Assert.assertTrue(el.getText().contains("error_message_text"));
```

This can help you with your requirement.

Comment: Thank you so much Abhinav. I have been asking people since last so many days and you have finally answered my question. U r a * :)

Comment: I have one more question Abhinav if you could help in please. When I click on details button and then it used to display error message as you have solved my problem. Now, there is a menu bar on the left side of this page where this error message was displayed. I am trying to go back to Product module but none of the buttons are getting clicked. This problem is only on this specific page. How do I write script in Juint for this please that buttons are not clickable.

Comment: Can you check if the button you are trying to click is in a frame or anything. I would need to have html of it. Also, If this has helped can you mark it as answer and raise a separate question for this and paste link so that someone can help. Mark this as answer